# Trocando valores entre funções com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá, no meu código como faço para que ao chamar a função (#imprimir) os valores contidos no array "dados" sejam obtidos da função gerarString.

```js
var gerarString = function () {
    var codproduto = 001,
    var newRow = 'teste',
    var iten = ([codproduto,newRow]);

    var dados = new Array();
    dados.push(iten);

    return dados;
}

$("#imprimir").on('click', function(){
    console.log(gerarString.dados);
 //$("#tabvenda").prepend(gerarString.getDados());
});
```

Comment: Não percebo bem o teu problema nem como pretendes usar essa array dentro de array. `console.log(gerarString());` parece-me a solução, mas acho que o problema real que tens é outro e seria interessante vê-lo para poder compreender e ajudar melhor.

Comment: @Sergio olhando todo o código será mais fácil de entender. O que pretendo fazer  é que ao selecionar algum checkbox, os dados (valor) serão armazenados em um array e serão enviados para a tabela 1 ao clicar em enviar. A intenção de usar um array dentro de outro array é que usaria o ''código do produto'' para validar caso o mesmo checkbox for clicado mais de uma vez, impedindo de ficar duplicado. https://jsfiddle.net/LGian/4Lpu7vao/3/

Comment: Acredito que deve existir uma forma mais "clean" para fazer este processo, mas ainda desconheço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas com seu código... O código abaixo mostra no console a saída:

> 1,teste

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="imprimir">Click Me!</button>

</body>
<script>
function gerarString() {
    var codproduto = 001;
    var newRow = 'teste';
    var iten = ([codproduto,newRow]);

    var dados = new Array();
    dados.push(iten);

    return dados;
}

$("#imprimir").on('click', function(){
    console.log(gerarString().toString());
 //$("#tabvenda").prepend(gerarString.getDados());
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Usando o toString() puxou os valores. Obrigado